# grails: How to derive custom views while keeping generated ones for reference

Tags: grails, code-generation

I am new to Grails and have setup my project. For all my domain classes I've created views and controllers using `generate-all`. Works fine.

Normally I'd probably stop to re-generate the code at some point. However, I'd like to 
 1. customize my views and controllers
 2. but still keep the possibility to re-generate the views and controllers - kind of as a "raw view" of the domain model.

--> Do I have to manually rename all the controllers and views to a custom name in order to have the custom and the generated files accessible in parallel? Or is there a mechanism that helps me doing so?

I found lots of documentation on static and dynamic scaffolding. Regarding the views customization, I just found hints to using the model constraints (beyond which I want to go) and adjusting the scaffolding templates (which I'd rather not, my changes will be individual per domain class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular reason why you need to create your own controllers, why not just add additional actions into the scaffolded controllers and have them render views with different names to the scaffolded views. Then your custom actions/views can happily co-exist with those created by scaffolding.

Comment: The `generate-all` command would overwrite the controller file, so the customer methods would be lost (I just tried that out). So you mean I should just switch to `generate-views` and make sure `generate-all` and `generate-controller` are not called any more?

Comment: yes, I don't think there's much point in repeatedly executing `generate-controller`, because the scaffolded actions probably won't change as you add/remove properties to/from the domain classes